# python pandas to drop lines and substitute values in specific columns of a csv file

Tags: python, csv, pandas

Can I use pandas  python module to do this:

1. automatically drop lines that do not have values at specific columns, for example columns 1 and 2
2. substitute the remaining missing values with a predefined value

I searched online and could not find a way to achieve both conditions.

Example:
This input (where NA is either a specific character or whitespace, and X is another character, known a priori)

```
NA, 1, 2, X, 5, 6
5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10
NA, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7
9, 8, 7, 6, 5, X
```

should become

```
5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10
9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 0
```

Comment: You can certainly do that, but to make it more concrete you can maybe give an example DataFrame, and what this should become.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To drop the rows with NA, you can do:

```
df.dropna()
```

To specify the columns where is checked for NaNs, you can provide the `subset` keyword argument, see http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html
To replace a certain value, you can do:

```
df.replace('X', 0)
```

Full example:

```
In [14]: df
Out[14]: 
    0  1  2  3  4   5
0 NaN  1  2  X  5   6
1   5  6  7  8  9  10
2 NaN  3  4  5  6   7
3   9  8  7  6  5   X

In [15]: df.dropna(subset=[0,1])
Out[15]: 
   0  1  2  3  4   5
1  5  6  7  8  9  10
3  9  8  7  6  5   X

In [16]: df.dropna(subset=[0,1]).replace('X', 0)
Out[16]: 
   0  1  2  3  4   5
1  5  6  7  8  9  10
3  9  8  7  6  5   0
```

Aside, it is not very efficient to have strings like `'X'` in numeric columns (this will make it of `object` type instead of `int` or `float`)

Comment: can I change the code above to make it work if I have 'someotherstring' instead of NaN?

Comment: also, the example above would not work, because I want to be able to not drop if NaN is present in some other column

Comment: updated the answer, you can use `subset` to specify the columns. You can always first replace 'somestring' with NaN, or just manually select the rows with `df[df['col']!='somestring']`